# Possible mistake in Gortz-Wedhorn's algebraic geometry book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I'm trying to solve exercise 2.14c in Gortz-Wedhorn's book on algebraic geometry, and it looks to me like it's wrong.

Here's the statement.  Let $X$ be a topological space and $i:Z \rightarrow X$ the inclusion of a subspace.  Assume that $Z$ is locally connected and that $\mathcal{F}$ is a constant sheaf on $Z$ with value $E$, where $E$ is some set.  Show that $i_{\ast}(\mathcal{F})_x = E$ for all $x \in \overline{Z}$.

Isn't the following a counterexample?  Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ (with the usual topology) and let $Z = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.  Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the sheaf of constant $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions on $Z$.  Then it looks to me like $i_{\ast}(\mathcal{F})_0 = \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}$.  Indeed, when calculating this stalk we can restrict to neighborhoods $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ of $0$.  The pullback of such a neighborhood to $Z$ is $(\epsilon,0)\cup(0,\epsilon)$, and a section of this is determined by the values on these two subintervals (which can be anything).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Of course this counterexample would not work for $Z = \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{(0,0)\}$. The following MO post seems relevant to your question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61528/is-the-direct-image-of-a-constant-sheaf-a-constant-sheaf

Comment: Good catch, Lena!